# Spring boot inject port number in static resources

Tags: html, spring, environment-variables, thymeleaf

i created a mock server with spring boot, from there i serve a static html page in /resources/setting/index.html,from there I can set the behavior of the server.
in the html page are hardcoded somewhere the port where the mockserver run.

what i would like to be able to do is to inject the port in the html file from the spring environment.

I searched around but didn't find much either because keywords tend to collide with other results

Comment: can't you use `server.http.port=8080`for this ?

Comment: Usually you use the `application.properties` file for this.